# btrfs-tools still depends on python although dependency explicitly removed

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Although dependency on python was explicitly removed using btrfs-tools_%.bbappend recipe, the package still depends on python3.

error:

```
$ bitbake some-image-qt
 * Solver encountered 1 problem(s):
 * Problem 1/1:
 *   - package btrfs-tools-6.1.3-r0.0.cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4 requires python3-core, but none of the providers can be installed
 *   - package python3-core-3.11.2-r0.0.cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4 can only be installed by a direct request
 *   - conflicting requests
 * 
 * Solution 1:
 *   - install python3-core-3.11.2-r0.0.cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4

 * Solution 2:
 *   - do not ask to install a package providing btrfs-tools
```

**btrfs-tools recipe pkg config:**

```
$ bitbake -e btrfs-tools
...
PACKAGECONFIG="     programs     convert          crypto-builtin  "
PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS=" --enable-convert --with-convert=ext2 --with-crypto=builtin --disable-lzo  --disable-documentation --enable-programs --disable-python --disable-libudev --disable-zoned --disable-zstd"
...
```

**recipe bbappend:**

```
$ cat meta-somelayer/recipes-devtools/btrfs-tools/btrfs-tools_%.bbappend
PACKAGECONFIG:remove = "python manpages"
```

**explicit exclusion**

```
$ cat conf/local.conf
PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = " \
....
python3-pygobject-dbg \
python3-pyyaml-dbg \
python3-pycairo-dbg \
python3-evdev-dbg \
python3-pygobject-dev \
python3-pycairo-dev \
python3-pyparsing-dev \
python3-pyparsing-dbg \
python3-dateutil-dev \
python3-pexpect-dev \
python3-ptyprocess-dev \
python3-evdev-dev \
python3-dateutil-dbg \
python3-pyyaml-dev \
python3-six-dev \
python3-ptyprocess-dbg \
python3-pexpect-dbg \
python3-six-dbg \
python3-core \
...
```

**content of btrf-tools ipk contains no dependency to python3:**

```
ar x btrfs-tools_6.1.3-r0.0_cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4.ipk
$ tar -xvf data.tar.xz 
./usr/
./usr/bin/
./usr/bin/btrfs
./usr/bin/btrfs-convert
./usr/bin/btrfs-find-root
./usr/bin/btrfs-image
./usr/bin/btrfs-map-logical
./usr/bin/btrfs-select-super
./usr/bin/btrfsck
./usr/bin/btrfstune
./usr/bin/fsck.btrfs
./usr/bin/mkfs.btrfs
./usr/lib/
./usr/lib/libbtrfs.so.0
./usr/lib/libbtrfs.so.0.1
./usr/lib/libbtrfsutil.so.1
./usr/lib/libbtrfsutil.so.1.2.0
```

Any help or advice would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I suspect, what happens is that the `inherit` directives are evaluated *before* the `PACKAGECONFIG` variable expansion would happen - the python dependency comes from `setuptools3-base` class, which is inherited dynamically, based on the (presumably) pre-expansion PACKAGECONFIG, which contains `python` by default, before you would remove it... I'm 99% sure it is a bug in the recipe. As a workaround if you add `RDEPENDS:${PN}:remove = "python3-core"` to your bbappend, it should get you further.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry I couldn't help tracing the bug any further. Took me some days to come here...